# List all audio files in device iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift3, mpmediaitem

I'm creating an app to list out all audio files stored in the device of types(*.mp3,*.wav), I got a sample code from `stackoverflow` but it's not listing the files. For testing purpose I have attached few files in the app package also, that also not detecting, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
 // All
    let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songs().items

    let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mediaItems!)

    print(mediaCollection)
    print(mediaItems)
```

Comment: Are you trying it with device or simulator?

Comment: @kkakkurt device

Comment: i think you need to pass the audio file extension, like "song.mp3"

Comment: What's your problem now? Is it giving an error or returning an empty array?

Comment: @kkakkurt its returning an empty array. i have attached few sample audio in project also fro testing.

Comment: @Joe MPMediaQuery associates the Media Library in the device. Project wise attaching songs are not detecting here. Check your app has the media access or not like Settings->Privacy->Media Library->Your app. Enable the switch to your app for accessing the media library.

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan Adding NSAppleMusicUsageDescription to Info.plist automatically asks for the user to enable accessing the media library while user wants to access media files.

Comment: @kkakkurt we are obvious even have a chance to "Don't allow" also. So access should be granted to the app as well Media Library should present in the Device.

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan If user disabled the access switch, you are right of course. I said that for the first usage of the app or if user didn't blocked the app access, in other words; default situation.

Answer (score 0):

`MPMediaQuery.songs().items` tries to reaches your music library. So you should make sure the "Music" app is available on your iphone. It can reach the audio files in your library.

And also you should add `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` to your Info.plist for privacy authority for reaching media files.

Comment: I think no need of "Music" app for checking the media items.